# How to create an NSDictionary with multiple keys?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, key, nsdictionary

I am not sure if what I am going to ask is actually an `NSDictionary` with multiple keys but ok.

What I want to do is create an `NSDictionary` with keys and values for my data and then convert it to `JSON` format. The `JSON` format would look exactly like this :

```
{
    "eventData": {
        "eventDate": "Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM",
        "eventLocation": {
            "latitude": 43.93838383,
            "longitude": -3.46
        },
        "text": "hjhj",
        "imageData": "raw data",
        "imageFormat": "JPEG",
        "expirationTime": 1339538400000
    },
    "type": "ELDIARIOMONTANES",
    "title": "accIDENTE"
}
```

I ve only used `NSDictionaries` like this :

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"eventDate", @"eventLocation", @"latitude"  nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"object1", @"object2", @"object3", nil]; 
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

But the above format is not all about key - value.
So my question is how would the `NSDictionary` be , to fit the `JSON` format??
Thanks for reading my post , and sorry if any confusion.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can have a `NSDictionary` inside another `NSDictonary`:

```
NSDictionary *eventLocation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"43.93838383",@"latitude",@"-3.46",@"latitude", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *eventData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:eventLocation,@"eventLocation", nil];
[eventData setObject:@"Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM" forKey:@"eventDate"];
[eventData setObject:@"hjhj" forKey:@"text"];
.
.
.
NSMutableDictionary *finalDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:eventData,@"eventData", nil];
[finalDictionary setObject:@"ELDIARIOMONTANES" forKey:@"type"];
[finalDictionary setObject:@"accIDENTE" forKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: You missed a comma between @"latitude" and nil.

Answer (score 17):

Now with Objective-C literals there is a much better, easier, and cleaner way of accomplishing this. Here is your exact dictionary with this new syntax:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
    @"eventData": @{
        @"eventDate": @"Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM",
        @"eventLocation": @{
            @"latitude": @43.93838383,
            @"longitude": @-3.46
        },
        @"text": @"hjhj",
        @"imageData": @"raw data",
        @"imageFormat": @"JPEG",
        @"expirationTime": @1339538400000
    },
    @"type": @"ELDIARIOMONTANES",
    @"title": @"accIDENTE"
};

// Prints: "43.93838383"
NSLog(@"%@", dictionary[@"eventData"][@"eventLocation"][@"latitude"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

**How to Create NSArray and with Access for object using NSDictionary ?**

**... Create NSArray**

```
NSArray *studentkeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"studentName", @"studentBirthDate", @"studentCity", @"studentMobile"  nil];

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Pravin", @"27/08/1990", @"Bhavnagar",@"7878007531", nil];
```

**...to Access to NSArray Object Using NSDictionary**

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the structure:
Your root object is `NSMutableDictionary`
`eventData` - key for object `NSMutableDictionary` with keys and objects:
->key `eventDate` object `NSString`
->key `eventLocation` object `NSMutableDictionary` with keys and objects:
----> key `latitude` object `NSNumber`
----> key `longitude` object `NSNumber`
-> key `text` object `NSString`
-> key `imageData` object `NSString` later converted to `NSData`
-> key `imageFormat` object `NSString`
-> key `expirationTime` object `NSNumber`
`type` key for object `NSString`
`title` key for object `NSString`

Comment: That looks great but could you help me with the obj-c syntax cause i am very new to this?

Comment: For future reference, use graver structure, meanwhile you can use the code I posted.

Comment: @Jacky Boy thank you very much for your answer. I think graver's structure is more readable and understandable. Would it be easy to edit your answer and post after your answer this structure(i mean the obj-syntax) to have both?

Comment: @donparalias I don't think that's very "ethical" thing to do. :)

Comment: Why not? I mean anyone of you , i just asked you because u were here. Its just for future reference! If i could i would accept both answers but for sure i thank you both very very much!

Comment: If you like @graver answer as well, you can upvote his answer, I already did. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple categories , you can follow this format

```
NSDictionary *jsonObject = @{
                           @"data1":@[
                              @{
                                @"title":@"A"

                                @"subData" : @[
                                @{
                                  @"title":@"aa"
                                 }]
                                }

                             ]
                         };
```

Comment: if you want to manage multiple categories using NSDictionary, you can follow this format