# how create array key and value in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am a new Iphone developer i need your help,

Any one provide me creating array with key and value, and how can fetch in xcode.

Comment: you only want creation of array.

Comment: Do you mean key-value pairs or you need a 2-D array?

Answer (score 12):

This the NSMutableDictionary. You can search for sample codes.
For example: [Create dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205974/how-to-create-an-nsdictionary-with-multiple-keys)

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject:@"object1" forKey:@"key1"];
```

Printing all keys and values of a Dict:

```
for (NSString* key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
   NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide me simple example?

Comment: I would like know how i can fetch by loop?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `NSDictionary` or `NSmutabledictionary` to achieve this you don't need to use and `NSArray`. Here is an example of how it works.

```
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // Don't always need this 
  // Note you can't use setObject: forKey: if you are using NSDictionary
  [dict setObject:@"Value1" forKey:@"Key1"];
  [dict setObject:@"Value2" forKey:@"Key2"];
  [dict setObject:@"Value3" forKey:@"Key3"];
```

then you can retrieve a value for a key by just doing.

```
  NSString *valueStr = [dict objectForKey:@"Key2"];
```

this will give the value of Value2 in the valueStr string.

to add objects to a none Mutable dictionary `NSDictionary` just do

```
 NSDictionary *dict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Value1", @"Key1", @"Value2", @"Key2", nil];
```

then just retrieve it the same way as an `NSMutableDictionary`. The difference between the two is that a `Mutable` dictionary can be modified after creation so can add objects to it with the `setObject:forKey` and remove objects with the `removeObjectFroKey:` whereas the none mutable dictionary can not be modified so once it has been created your stuck with it until it has been released, so no adding or remove objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to fetch this array by loop, show key and value by loop.


fetching way
NSString *valueStr = [dict objectForKey:@"Key2"];

I need to fetch by loop all key and value, i need to search value in array.

Comment: @user1825965 So you what to be able to get the values and keys in a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what a NSDictionary / NSMutableDictionary does:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[ myDictionary setObject:@"John" forKey:@"name"];
[ myDictionary setObject:@"Developer" forKey:@"position"];
[ myDictionary setObject:@"1/1/1984" forKey:@"born"];
```

The difference is that, in the mutable one, you can add/modify entries after creating it, but not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to add object anymore, you can create a non mutable dictionary:

```
NSDictionary* dict= @{ @"key1" : @"value1" , @"key2" : @"value2" };
```

If you don't need key value pairs that's an array:

```
NSArray* array= @[ @"value1" , @"value2", @"value3" ];
```