# How to define a nsmutabledictionary with an object (a variable varying with time) and key?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to define a nsmutabledictionary which holds a variable data from a source. The value/object of my nsmutabledictionary is varying data (with time) and key is a string representing the source. Hence the values are unknown variables however the key is known.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an NSDictionary with multiple keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205974/how-to-create-an-nsdictionary-with-multiple-keys)

Answer (score 0):

An **NSDictionary** is meant to handle, only non-changing values.
Once set, the values can only be read, and no other object-key entities can be added and/or changed.

If you wish to fulfill your problem, simply use a **NSMutableDictionary.**
Now, you can simply keep the value changing for a particular key.

Just use,

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"number",nil];
[mDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"number"];
```

And, then if changed, you can just simply keep reusing,

```
[mDict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"number"];
```

Just try this out, and see if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method which is triggered at the events(time) on which you want to set the data for a key in NSDictonary, suppose the method is -

```
- (void) resetDataForKeyIndictionary:(id)data;
```

Call/ schedule the above method on the events/time at which you want to change the data for a key in dict.

But before this declare & create a dictionary instance as-

```
NSMutableDictionary* m_dict;

m_dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

& set the data for key in method as-

```
- (void) resetDataForKeyIndictionary:(id)data
{
    [m_dict setObject:data ForKey:@"key"];
}
```